# how to ignore some fields when using BeanCopier to copy properties

Tags: java

Now I want to copy fields from A class to B class, my code like this:

```
private static final <S, D> D doCopy(S src, D dest, Converter converter) {
    Class<?> clsSrc = src.getClass();
    Class<?> clsDest = dest.getClass();
    BeanCopier copier = getBeanCopier(clsSrc, clsDest);
    copier.copy(src, dest, converter);
    return dest;
}
```

because some fields of A class fields type not match B class, if I copied directly. It will throw some error, is it possible to ignore some fields when doing copy? I read the BeanCopier source code and did not find any way?

Comment: Have you considered copying the fields you want? If the `BeanCopier` API doesn't give you the behavior you want, you can always do it yourself. The point of beans is that everything is public, not just to fancy APIs but to you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties()` which has an optional String array of property names to ignore

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(srcObj,destObj,["property1NameToIgnore","property2NameToIgnore"]);
```